# delete file after sending to user

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I try to send a file to the user with this function

```
Yii::$app->response->sendFile($tmp_filename, 'test.RData');
```

Now I want the file to be deleted after sending. I know that there's an event handler for `send` method in `yii/web/Response` called `EVENT_AFTER_SEND`

I tried to access this handler with the following code:

```
Event::on(\yii\web\Response::className(), \yii\web\Response::EVENT_AFTER_SEND, function ($event) {
          unlink($event->response->filename);  
});
```

But my problem is

a) I'm not sure if this is the right way

b) how to access the filename inside the event

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will send the file immediately, you could

```
header('....');
echo file_get_contents(path/of/file)
unlink(path/of/file);
```

You could think to create a temporary file, so the operative system will delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This was my plan b. Thought I could make it the yii way ;-)

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem this week. The [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-component.html#on()-detail) says that we can use the `$data` parameter to add any variable we want on this callback. Here is a example:

```
Yii::$app->response->sendFile('/path/of/my/temp/file')->on(\yii\web\Response::EVENT_AFTER_SEND, function($event) {
    unlink($event->data);
}, '/path/of/my/temp/file');
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I will definitively try this out!